JPanel within a JPanel will not resize using setSize()? No active layout managers being used either
What I am currently trying to make are 3 panels in a frame that is laid out via GridLayout(), and each of the 3 panels would have their own panels within them that would be containing text. The top-most panel would only contain a single line (a fake email address), while the panel below it would contain the contents of an email. However, when I try setting senderPanel (the panel within the other panel), the panel size does not change and stays zero.
private void showLastJFrame(WindowAdapter windowAdapter){
    JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();
    frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); // We don't want to exit the entire program when frame 2 is closed
    frame3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

    frame3.setSize(1600, 900);
    frame3.addWindowListener(windowAdapter);
    frame3.setVisible(true);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setSize(new Dimension(frame3.getWidth()/3,900));
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();

    // Set bounds and background color
    panel1.setBackground(null);

    panel2.setBackground(new Color(100,255,100));

    panel3.setBackground(new Color(100,100,255));


    String[] test = makeEmail.getEmail();
    System.out.println(test[1]);


    // Add labels to panels
    
    JPanel senderPanel = new JPanel();
    JLabel senderLabel  = new JLabel(test[1]);
    senderPanel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    senderPanel.setOpaque(true);
    senderPanel.setSize(new Dimension(panel1.getWidth(),100));
    System.out.println(senderPanel.getSize());
    panel1.add(senderPanel);
   // senderPanel.add(senderLabel);
    System.out.println(panel1.getWidth()+ "" + panel1.getHeight());
  //  JPanel bodyPanel = new JPanel();
    //JLabel bodyLabel = new JLabel(test[2]);


    //bodyPanel.add(bodyLabel);
    
   // panel1.add(bodyLabel);`

I've already tried making a grid layout within each panel so that the subpanel (senderPanel) would appear, which worked, however I can't readjust their size. I have also already used setSize() on panel1 (the main panel) to try and give the subpanels reference dimensions so I could fit them. Additionally I have tried using a FlowLayout() for senderPanel, but that doesn't resize it either.

I don't see where you're adding panel1 to the frame so it might not actually be rendered at all. Btw, you should try not to set absolute sizes yourself as interfering with the layout manager will just cause a lot of headaches. You also wouldn't want to do all the layouting yourself. Instead try to look for a layout manager that allows resizing (e.g. FlowLayout with min/max/preferred sizes for the panels, or Miglayout (older but extremely useful external layout lib))

"No active layout managers being used" - according posted code, the layout manager is not being reset, but JPanel uses FlowLayout as default manager. Better include a [mre] in the question. And usually best to use LayoutManager! Also note from the documentation of setSize(): "This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy."

I can't readjust their size. - You miss the point of using a layout manager and the GridLayout in particular. The layout manager will set the size of each component based on the rules of the layout manager. The GridLayout will make all the components the same size based on the space available. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on Layout Managers for working examples. If you want panels with different sizes then you don't use a GridLayout. Maybe a GridBagLayout.
